# MySQL + python table FETCH module

Tags: python, mysql, compilation

```
name=input("input CUSTOMERID to search :")

    # Prepare SQL query to view all records of a specific person from
    # the SALESPRODUCTS TABLE LINKED WITH SALESPERSON TABLE.
    sql =    "SELECT * selling_products.customer \
              FROM customer \
              WHERE customer_products.CUSTOMERID == name"

    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)

    # Fetch all the rows the sql result of SQL1.
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print("\n\n****** TABLE MASTERLIST*********")
    print("CUSTOMERID \t PRODUCTID \t DATEOFPURCHASE")
    print("**************")

    for row in results:
        print (row[0],row[1],row[2])
```

Python would compile the code above, but it will not return any output. Help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: is <URGENT> a framework?

Answer (score 0):

i think you sql should be:

```
sql =    """SELECT * selling_products.customer 
          FROM customer 
          WHERE customer_products.CUSTOMERID == {name}""".format(name=name)
```